# Accessing Table Data ONLY From View

Tags: sql-server, permissions, view

I have a table '[Employee]' , and I want to allow access  to certain people only through [View] , using a grant.I am trying first to do it with a single user [User]  and then do it for a collection of users through a role.  I know I can use :

GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT : : [VIEW] TO [User] ;

And I can also create a role [Role] , and use:

GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT : : [VIEW] TO [Role]

My question is whether this permission somehow implicitly excludes all others,
i.e., do the two grants above prevent any of the [Users][Roles] from having any other type of access to '[Employee]' ( Read, Select, Update ), or do I have to expressly prohibit said users, roles from having additional access?

I assume this has to see with membership of [User] and the people in [Role] in other logins or existing user types which may have been granted said permissions either explicitly or as part of role membership? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you grant SELECT to 'public' role, you must explicitly grant access to each user, group or database role.

For simplicity, you can create a new database role, (i.e. my_users), then grant select to this role and finally add new users to the role.

Comment: Thanks @McNets, I just want to make sure that no other type of permission is granted to [user]. May I just assign [user] to 'public' and only Grant  'Select' to 'public'. Would this guarantee that my user can only select? Sorry if I am confused, I just want to see what I need to do so that [user] can only use 'select'.

Comment: It is not recommended, create a new database role (i.e. company_users), grant access to it, and then add users to this role.